# Using Spring in a portlet without Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, portlet, vaadin

Is there a way to develop portlets with spring without using the DispatcherPortlet? I want to use other technologies for the UI, mainly Vaadin. Spring is used for DI and other stuff. Is there something similar to ContextLoaderListener class in the Portlet side?

Comment: I don't think there is another portlet implementation in spring except this MVC based. Ofcourse we can make beans directly as noel writter, but how it will be treated as a portlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for a more detailed answer than what Noel gave. Maybe there is some best practice to this? Here is my current solution:

Give the xml file locations as a init parameter to my portlet.
My init method looks something like this

```
@Override
public void init(PortletConfig config) throws PortletException {
    super.init(config);
    String configLocations = config.getInitParameter("contextConfigLocation");
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext springContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext();
    springContext.setConfigLocation(configLocations);
    springContext.refresh();
    config.getPortletContext().setAttribute(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, springContext);
}
```

Now I can access my applicationContext through PortletContext every time I need.

```
(ApplicationContext) portalContext.getAttribute(APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
```

APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE is just string constant that I made up. I'm still open for better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html): You can create an `ApplicationContext` as follows:

```
ApplicationContext context =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"services.xml", "daos.xml"});
```

Referencing xml files on your classpath.

You can then get beans by calling `context.getBean("beanName")`. No need for Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PortletApplicationContextUtils to retrieve the web application context:

ApplicationContext ctx = PortletApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getPortletContext());

Then you just need to add some configuration on your web.xml.

Comment: How do you initialise the application context with PortletApplicationContextUtils?